# List of file names in a table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to create a Swing gui where when I click browse I should get a text field giving the directory's path and a table of all the files in that directory.

I was able to get the first part(i.e. path). Can somebody help me in getting the files in a table?

I tried this:

```
public void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JFileChooser filesave = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "TEXT File", ".txt", "text");
        filesave.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = filesave.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {

                File file = filesave.getSelectedFile();

                PrintWriter os = new PrintWriter(file + ".txt");

                for (int row = 0; row < jTable1.getRowCount(); row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < jTable1.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                        os.print(jTable1.getColumnName(col));
                        os.print(": ");
                        os.println(jTable1.getValueAt(row, col));

                    }

                }
                os.close();
                System.out.println("Done!");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*I tried this*" .... and what happened? Please [edit] your question and tell us.

Comment: No file is added into the table.

Comment: Please read the second sentence of my last comment.

Comment: See also the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for 'file list in a table'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, nothing is added to the table because you didn't add anything to the table, no surprise here. If you ask me, some information is missing, but the normal way to achive this is...

1. create a TableModel (by extending AbstractTableModel)
2. set it in the JTable
3. when your button is clicked, update the TableModel, which should notify the listeners
4. Bingo, your table is updated

You can use a DefaultTableModel for that, no problem here. Search for it and you'll find enough tutorials go get by.